# Bad format after casting a numeric to wstr in a SSIS expression

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, etl, ssis-2014

I need to cast a double to wstr in an expression in a derived column for building a message. When I do that with the number `0.5` : `(DT_WSTR, 50)0.5` . Then, I got a bad format: `,5`. The `0` is missing and the decimal separator has changed.

How can I get a number with the format `0.5` when casting, please?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check the locale (LCID) for the given step. Odds are it is something which uses commas (,) for decimal representation (and likely periods (.) for thousands separators). May also explain the dropping of leading zeros.

Comment: can you please show sample data with desired derived column

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert this column to `WSTR`, you can use [Data Conversion Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/data-conversion-transformation) to achieve this.

Also if your requirements is only to convert this column without any further use, you can map directly this column to a `WSTR` destination column without any conversion. because the SSIS [Implicit data conversion](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx#Remarks) allow conversion from decimal to string.